# Simulation doesn't fully fill the Gazebo window

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When launching Gazebo the simulation view doesn't fully fill the Gazebo window. I get borders that are either black or filled old previously rendered material (e.g. background image of that screen).

Gazebo doesn't give me any useful feedback on this when being started in `--verbose` mode.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: image description]

I can use the border to scroll and move the content of the "simulation view", but it never shows anything there. The size of the border seems to be some ratio of the whole window, so if I resize it I get the same proportions of used and unused windows space.

This is with:

- (K)Ubuntu 18.04
- X-Server 1.20.4
- Nvidia driver 430.50
- Kernel 5.0.0-36
- Gazebo 9.0.0+dfsg5-3ubuntu1+ppa2

Also the buttons of the visualization part are very low resolution and so is the Gazebo startup display. All the rest of the window is fine though.

Any ideas for solution or debugging steps?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24193/simulation-doesn%27t-fully-fill-the-gazebo-window/) by [Matthias Mayr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21013/matthias-mayr/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-12-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bionade24](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24344/bionade24/) on 2020-03-08**:
Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am going to cross-post the solution from https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/2688:
I added two script files:

**/usr/local/bin/gazebo**

```
   #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   /usr/bin/env QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=[1.0] /usr/bin/gazebo $@
```

**/usr/local/bin/gzclient**

```
   #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   /usr/bin/env QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=[1.0] /usr/bin/gzclient $@
```

They would probably need to be executable.
That allows to use this modification without messing with the package management.

---

Originally posted by [Matthias Mayr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21013/matthias-mayr/) with karma: 1 on 2021-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0